# attribute name of minimum order amount > free shipping > sales > shipping method > configuration > system

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to code in price.phtml

My code is

700 ){
  echo "+ most selected item";}?>

I have hard coded 700 which I want to change with appropriate attribute name of minimum order amount > free shipping > sales > shipping method > configuration > system in magento 1.9.3.9

I do not know what & how to replace 700.

Answer (score 0):

Change 700 to:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal");
```